# load the view and controls as per posted mode in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am currently working in the asp.net mvc 2 with C#. it is new for me. 
**Scenario is:**
I am showing the Edit page in the edit mode.this page have the dropodown control. It fills with the steps like Step1, step2 , step3, step4, step5. Ok? Now I want to load the Edit view page such a way that , If dropdown has selected as Step 3 then it must make visible the two more buttons as "NEXT" and "Modify". And if the selected is Step 5 (last step then make visible "Finish", and must make invisible "NEXT" buttons.
In Short want to create the wizard control, like in normal asp.net . How to achieve this?

What I have to do there ? Javascript ? Controller level? JQuery or what ?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to reload the page this sounds like a job for jQuery/javascript

edit: show us what you have already, and what functionality you've got so far.

so there are 5 steps, and the only thing changing are the buttons? aren't this 5 pages?

Comment: Ok , let say I want to avoid reload the page then , what i have to follow? Please guide me ...